# Trouble using Zurb Foundation with ECharts

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, echarts, referenceerror

I'm new to using Zurb Foundation and I'm having trouble to combine it with the ECharts library. Because of some "dirty testing" in the dist folder I'm pretty sure this is possible to achieve.

I couldn't find any useful instructions for including additional JavaScript in Foundation projects.

It seems the ECharts script gets loaded but it doesn't work, there's this error:

> ReferenceError ("echarts is not defined") occurring on calling echarts.init( ... )

What did I do:

- I've put the echarts.min.js file into the /src/assets/js/ folder of my project.
- the file is referenced in the head section of my layout file as described here https://echarts.apache.org/en/tutorial.html
- I also added a reference to echarts.min.js in the config.yml file of my project.

Comment: You might want to try `window.echarts`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but this only changes the error type (now it shows TypeError: window.echarts is undefined)

Comment: Can you provide some code so we can reproduce this? Otherwise it is mostly guesswork.